# Need help finding average

Tags: java

I cant seems to figure out how to calculate the average score from a user inputted amount of scores. I also cant get it to stop excepting inputs more then 100 or less then 0. Can someone show me what Im doing wrong? Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   int sum = 0;
   int inputNumber;
   int numberExams;
   float averageScore;
   double max = 0; 
   double min = 101;      


   System.out.println("Enter the total number of exams you want a average");
   numberExams = scan.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Please enter " + numberExams + " numbers:");

   for(int i = 1; i<=numberExams ;i++){          
    inputNumber = scan.nextInt();
    sum = sum + inputNumber;
    System.out.println();

   if(inputNumber > max){
    max = inputNumber;
}
   if(inputNumber < min){
    min = inputNumber;
}
   if(inputNumber > -1 && inputNumber < 101){
    sum = sum + inputNumber;
}
   else{
    System.out.println("You entered a number that wasn't in the range of 0 to 100");
}
} 


    averageScore = sum / numberExams;

System.out.println( "The Max Exam Score is: " + max );
System.out.println( "The Minimum Exam Score is: " + min );    
System.out.println("The Average Exam Score is: " + averageScore );
}
}
```

Comment: Check what happens to `min` and `max` when you input an invalid entry. (Also, you always increase `numberExams` on bad input as well as on good.)

Comment: You're adding the input twice to the sum.

Comment: You should count the number of valid inputs. Perhaps you intended `averageScore = (double) sum / numberExams;`

Comment: Also, be careful when dividing 2 integers. For example, 15 / 4 does not give you the real average. Try using doubles.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the check for your range first before assigning to `min` or `max`.

This works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  int sum = 0;
  double averageScore;
  double max = 0;
  double min = 101;

  System.out.println("Enter the total number of exams you want a average");
  final int numberExams = scan.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Please enter " + numberExams + " numbers:");

  for (int i = 0; i < numberExams; ++i) {
    final int inputNumber = scan.nextInt();

    if (inputNumber >= 0 && inputNumber <= 100) {
      System.out.println();

      if (inputNumber > max) {
        max = inputNumber;
      }
      if (inputNumber < min) {
        min = inputNumber;
      }
      sum += inputNumber;
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("You entered a number that wasn't in the range of 0 to 100");
    }
  }

  averageScore = sum / numberExams;

  System.out.println("The Max Exam Score is: " + max);
  System.out.println("The Minimum Exam Score is: " + min);
  System.out.println("The Average Exam Score is: " + averageScore);
}
```

Note that you still have the issue that if you receive invalid input, you'll be counting the wrong number of scores. You could handle that a couple of different ways. One would be to decrement `i` inside the `else` block.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `sum = sum + inputNumber` twice in your `for-loop`.

Also, you need to convert your `int`s to `double` to compute the average:

```
double average = ((double) sum) / numberExams;
```